# How to solve a sum containing m^2/m!

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac{(i^2)}{i!} $$ How to get $2*e-1$

Comment: I tried to rewrite i! as i*(i-1) so it will be i/(i-1)! but no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Look at $e^x = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$, perform the correct combination of differentiating and multiplication by $x$, and you will get a sum with terms $\frac{i^2x^i}{i!}$. Then you may evaluate at $x = 1$.

Comment: $\sum_{i = 2}^\infty \frac{i^2}{i!} =  \sum_{i = 2}^\infty \frac{2*i}{i!} = 2*\sum_{i = 2}^\infty \frac{i*1^î}{i!} = 2*\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \frac{1^î}{i!} = 2*e -1 ??$

Comment: How did you get $i^2$ to become $2i$?

Comment: differentiating

Comment: @MartinLupták That's not what I am telling you to do. I'm telling you to insert an $x^i$ into the expression, and differentiate _with respect to_ $x$.

Comment: Sorry i see my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{i^2}{i!}=\frac{i(i-1)+i}{i!}=\frac{1}{(i-2)!}+\frac{1}{(i-1)!}$

so your sum splits into two series of $e$, save for a $1$ which has to be added and subtracted.

Comment: I think this is the most transparent way to go about this, though it takes some cleverness. +1

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not using $i$ in this context. Your series can be written
$$
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{k!}=
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{k}{(k-1)!}=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1}{k!}
$$
Consider the power series
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1}{k!}x^k
$$
so your series is $f(1)$.

Integrating term by term we have
$$
\int_0^x f(t)\,dt=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}x^{k+1}=
x\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}x^{k}=x(e^x-1)
$$
Therefore
$$
f(x)=(xe^x-x)'=e^x+xe^x-1
$$
and $f(1)=2e-1$.

Answer (score 0):

egreg started nicely with
$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{k!}=
\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{k}{(k-1)!}=
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1}{k!}
$
but then got more complicated than necessary.

Continue like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k+1}{k!}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k!}
+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}
+(-1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}
+(-1+e)\\
&=e+(-1+e)\\
&=2e-1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Yes now i understand. Thank you !

Comment: I just wanted to show an alternative technique and not to redo momo's answer, which is essentially the same as yours.